# ¿Cómo invertir cada palabra de una cadena? (Sin slicer ni split)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por ejemplo, si la cadena fuera **Hola mundo**, el resultado esperado sería **aloH odnum**.

Este es lo que intenté:

```
text_inv = ""
for i in texto:
    text_inv = i + text_inv
```

Comment: `' '.join(texto.split()[::-1])`

Comment: Parece que tienes un profesor de C/C++ dando clases de Python. ¿Para que vas a aprender Python si vas a usarlo como C/C++?

Comment: A veces creo que hacen esas cosas los profes, y supongo que viene bien para aprender. Cosas como "haga una función que haye el maximo numero sin usar la función max y así". Debe ser para que los alumnos puedan aprender a hacer su propia función cuando sea necesario.

Comment: Manejo de listas es una parte tan vital de Python que si prescindes de ella, deja de ser Python. Hay mil otras cosas de más provecho para aprender y practicar.

Comment: No seguiré hablando de esto para no contaminar demasiado los comentarios (si querés seguimos en el chat) pero en mi solución, usé una lista. Así que supongo que eso también se enseñó en su clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nota: Debido a las condiciones aclaradas en el titulo, parece ser un ejercicio de clase, por lo que mi respuesta se enfoca en no usar modulos, cumplir las condiciones antes mencionadas y ser lo más entendible para un nivel bajo de conocimiento de programación. Además, asume que cada palabra está separada por espacios.

---

Podés lograrlo con el siguiente código:

```
cadena = "esta es una cadena de prueba"

words = []
word = ""

for c in cadena:
    if(c == " "):
        words.append(word)
        word = ""
    else:
        word = c + word

words.append(word)

print(" ".join(words))
```

El plan es crear una lista de palabras que empiece vacía y una variable word que almacenará la palabra que estamos invirtiendo. Posteriormente, recorremos cada caracter de la cadena con un bucle for. Si el caracter es un espacio, agregamos la palabra ya invertida a la lista y reestablecemos la variable word a una cadena vacía para empezar a invertir la siguiente palabra. De lo contrario, "agregamos" el caracter al principio de word y guardamos la nueva cadena creada en la variable word.
Una vez recorrida toda la cadena, nos queda una palabra sin agregar a la lista, por lo que la agregamos.

Comment: es una tarea y hasta el omemnto hemos visto lo más básico de python, y hace poco vimos ciclos(while) y estamos recien viendo las funcion for, pero nada más que eso, y tambien vimos el rebanador, pero no el que tiene para diferentes parámetros :(

Comment: Entiendo. En ese caso espero que mi respuesta haya servido para reforzar esos conocimientos c: Por cierto, podés apoyarme aceptando mi respuesta nwn